# React Native: Text disappears from buttons on smaller screens

Tags: android, react-native, styling

I'm creating a phone app with react native. And I've been testing it on a 5' screen on an emulator, and it's been working fine. I tried testing it on a smaller screen on a real phone, and the text disappears off the buttons. When I click on a button, the text appears again, in the correct size. Any advice on how to handle that?

Do I resize my text according to screen size?

This is my code:

```
    class CreateAccountButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.label = ""
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight
         style={styles.button2}
         onPress={this.props.onPress}
        >
         <Text style = {{fontSize: 20, color:'white',}} > {this.props.label} </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

button2: {
        backgroundColor: '#24572c',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 15,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'white',
        width: 250,
        height: 50,
    },
```

This is where the component is called in the code.

```
<View style={styles.spacer}>
                <LoginButton label='Sign In' onPress={this._onLoginPress.bind(this)} />
                <CreateAccountButton label= 'Create Account' onPress={this._onCreateAccountPress.bind(this)} />
          </View>

spacer: {
        flex: 1,
        // backgroundColor: 'pink',
    },
```

A new development for this, is that it seems that on the debug versions, the text appears on the buttons, when I run on my phone, but on the release version the text doesn't appear. I still haven't been able to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Show details of your `onPress` inside your parent component

Comment: @IsaacSekamatte Sorry I took so long to answer, paused my development for a while. I added the rest of the code.